# Why is my model coming apart when posing its armature?

Tags: mesh, armature

Hi I am trying to animate a bird rig that I made but when I try to pose the armature the bird model comes apart, almost like the faces are moving independent of each other.

I am curious why or how this is happening. I actually like the effect of whatever has happened  and am hoping to possibly apply whatever is happening to some other models. But so far I've had no luck duplicating it
[image: posed]

I tried adjusting the weights, but I'm not sure if I did it properly, most of the models I make only have to have their weights adjusted minimally.

[image]

Comment: Please show your modifiers on the mesh, the armature modifier settings, weight paint.

Comment: Better could be a link of your file ;)

Comment: Maybe edge splits can cause this? Or some wrong playing around with shape keys and stuff like that? I don't know for sure, but long time ago I had similar problem...

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger I just uploaded a copy of my file. However I did have an edge split modifier that I applied to my mesh. I think your answer may be exactly what I did

Comment: @AdriansNetlis  please see below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Image above. A similar effect can be achieved with edge split and armature.  The mesh started as a cube.  This technique alone is a bit difficult.

[image]

Image above. Single Armature, two bone chains, no weight painting.

[image]

Image above.  Separation of faces.  Edge Split was applied. Vertex group created basis and key1 which is scaled smaller.  Bind armature to key1. Display basis.  Keys inspired by comment by Adrians Nellis.

Easier to control.

Footnote

[image]

[image]

Image above.  One armature, four bone chains.  No weight paint with brush, thus you see some vertices in undesired places. It seemed best not to have a weight paint exercise. Weights were modified with [limit total] value 1 in weight paint mode.  No artist merit here.  The first frames numbered <= 103 have the same shape key values.  Only the highest numbered frame has different shape key values.  Shape keys are not required for discontinuity of faces, yet changing face size is convenient.  Dotted Lines....

- Create Mesh
- Mark Sharp and Apply Edge Split
- Scale Faces Smaller by .5 in edit mode.  Different faces have space between them.
- Armature Modifier is parented.
- Create Shape Key, Basis and Key1. Key1 scale Larger by 2 in edit mode. (2 * .5 = 1).  This visual appears to eye as closed surface.
- The two different Keys minimize manual painting and promote easier parenting to intentionally produce surface discontinuities.
- Use Key1 influence 1 full strength

Comment: I think this is what I did. I had no idea that edge split  modifier would have this effect. I thought it primarily affected how the mesh was shaded, ie to have smooth shading with sharp edges. Can you explain why it does this

Comment: It's how edge split works. In order to make the edges look sharp, edge split as it's name implies split the edge of an object where the user indicates. So imaging a cube with smooth shading applied, with 4 edges selected for edge split to act on. If the edge have 4 vertices it would now have 8 vertices after edge split is applied. Hence the single mesh will now have 2 sub meshes at the "edit level".

Comment: @m.fessler you should have received a few more points for your question above ... do you understand the part of Key1?

Comment: @hawkenfox That makes perfect sense, thank you for the explanation.

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger I'll admit I have never used or heard of shape keys before. I did look some information up on them and I definitely am going to start using them. I understand exactly what you are saying about how using them would make things easier. Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 2):

Im preety sure your Bird's mesh doesnt have all the faces connected to each other. One way to clean this would be to select your bird and go into edit mode. Then, select all the faces by pressing <kbd>A</kbd>. After, press  the "Remove Doubles" button. It should connect all the faces together, if not most of them.

[image]

Comment: I tried this solution and it partially worked. However I really wanted to know  how it happened in the first place so I could replicate the result, But thank you!