# My mesh comes apart every time I parent it to my armature

Tags: modeling, rigging, bones

I'm trying to parent my mesh to my armature, but it seems as though as if every time I do so, my mesh loses its faces. [image]

I'm pretty sure that it's being caused by the lack of green bones on my mesh for some reason, and I'm not sure how to fix those.[image]
I've also tried regenerating my rig with and from rigidify, but it just seems to turn out the same. If anyone knows, thank you and have a nice day!

Comment: Did you *apply scale* to your mesh (Ctrl+A>apply scale)?

Comment: looks like the split edge modifier problem in a few post earlier. You don't happen to have any modifier applied to your mesh have you?

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47422/why-is-my-model-coming-apart-when-posing-its-armature see this post, if it helps.